# Creating an elongated text effect

Tags: typography, typesetting, illustrator-effects

What is the most efficient way to achieve an effect such as the one pictured below?

[image]

Comment: To be honest i would draw it. It takes about 10 minutes tops

Comment: Have tried converting to paths and using the anchor points to manipulate the letters as well as using line/circle tools to do it manually. Had varying results as not using this typeface specifically so just wondered how others would go about doing it! Thanks for the help though guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create your text in Illustrator and convert it to paths. Next, use the direct selection tool to drag a selection box around just the points that make up the lower parts of the letters. Drag these points down until the text is as tall and stretched as you want it.

You may need to experiment and make some adjustments to get a pleasing result, but that’s the basic method.

Comment: WHy would you do that the font here is very easy to make manually with line and circle tool

Comment: True, if you’ve got the skills, but my method would still be quicker. Seconds versus minutes.

Comment: Not really you would have to find a fint that makes this easy. Most likely thtat would mean youd need to atleast redraw the V

Comment: Agree to disagree. I’ve achieved this very effect using the method described and it works a treat. Lots of fonts lend themselves to this treatment.

Comment: OBviously there are only so many letters where this is a problem

Comment: @joojaa I think you are completely mistaken, see my answer.

Comment: @Ovaryraptor Well you can do that, but the effort you put in is at par with drawing the thing by hand. ON the otherhand if you were going to do this with 20 letters then yes.

Comment: @joojaa Is it? I don't see how, you'd be fiddling and fighting to make the angles. Far better to just work off of a base then edit it. That way you maintain visual consistency.

Answer (score 2):

Before you even start you should spend some time selecting an appropriate font. Look for letterforms that are easy to transform. Obviously sans-serif fonts will be simpler than serif ones.

Once you have your word typed out in Illustrator you need to convert it to paths by doing `Object > Expand > OK` and then ungroup it <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>.

Then using the direct selection tool select a letterform to see the points to see which you need to remove and simplify to make stretching easier and more uniform.

My example is for the letter V. I removed 2 extra points that would have caused non-uniform stretching and I simplified the center to 1 point from 2.

[image]

You will need to experiment and adjust the letters to get the desired result, but this is a nice rundown of how to get started.